# How to avoid Repositioning of Goalposts when using Improve Details bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties, specific-question

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945891/responsive-css-circles) has been `Locked` until resolution.
"Repositioning of Goalposts" was interprited from a question using "Improve Details" bounty.

What the question has been reverted back too:
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12945891/11

The final revision of this question before the bounty started:
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12945891/10

**Important to note:**

- A solution was never found before the bounty, only pieces of the solution.
- The bounty was started to "Improve Details", not to ask another question.

*Details were added to the question to target in on the problems, give better context, and guide users to contribute more than what was already known.*

---

**How can I avoid a situation like this in the future - when I collect information along the way to build a better question but still want to engage a bounty to "Improve Details" of the answers?**

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, from what I could see, there were answers that addressed the original question before you modified it to ask for optimizations.

Additionally, [you made an edit specifically stating a "New Goal"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12945891/6); this is a *highly* destructive edit, which invalidates the [current highest-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12945993/50776) on the page.

That said, if you have answers to the question, but want to *expand* the question in a way that would invalidate the answers, then *don't* (the bounty is irrelevant here); you should ask a *new* question.  Specifically, in this case, you should have asked a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as that is the Stack Exchange site that specializes in optimizing existing, *working* code.

Comment: "New Goal" added rev 6 made it a kind of [“chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/165773)...

Comment: @gnat Yeah, I don't disagree, but was trying not to frame it that way (comes off a little hard).

Comment: well I'd say changes like that are quite hard on those who put their effort into answering the original question :(

Comment: @gnat Yeah, that and I ran out of votes for the day because of the "nicer to mods" thread, otherwise, I'd upvote your comment.