# "Marked as duplicate" text doesn't make sense for questions that have no answer

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, wording

The new "marked as duplicate" text says:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

In some cases though, users like to re-post their questions rather than fixing their closed originals, so we close them as dupes of that original. In this case, the text simply doesn't apply.  It is also the only special case (not counting meta posts) where closing as duplicate does not require any answers on the original question.

If both duplicate questions have been asked by the same user, the text should be special cased to reflect that:

> This question has been asked before by the same user.  Instead of re-posting, the original question should have been edited and clarified.

… which will provide better guidance, and it will only mention existence of any answers when it is relevant and true.

Comment: Hm, if it's a case of a user re-posting the same question, why not just delete it right after you close it and be done with it?

Comment: In most cases: To leave a comment explaining what's wrong with re-posting and keep it  (at least for a while) to show that this behavior is not encouraged.

Comment: @slhck I think deleting would convey the latter just as well, and for the former... you could leave a comment on the question you're keeping?

Comment: Not always that easy. For example here, we have a different user with whom I couldn't even communicate on the other question: http://superuser.com/questions/547612/how-to-exclude-a-user-from-the-ip-ban-list-v2

Comment: For those who, like me, thought referring to a duplicate *without* answers was only possible on Meta, [read again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate): *"... close targets are restricted to answered questions even when specifying the ID or URL directly (with the exception of questions from the same author, and meta posts). Moderators can override this last restriction if necessary."*