# An "Exact Duplicate" question doesn't mean there's already a helpful answer

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

My duplicate question was just closed for being an exact duplicate.

[image: EXACT DUPLICATE]

So naturally I looked to see what this answer is.

[image: RELEVANT ANSWER]

This answer doesn't really apply. It's a "me too", but it doesn't tell me if this won't happen by policy, will happen maybe, or anything.

Note that I'm not complaining about the answer, it's relevant on meta, I know. I'm complaining about the "this question has been answered here:" when it hasn't been.

On a main site, this banner would be incredibly frustrating and lead to "THIS DIDN'T WORK" or various other comments on the referenced question asking for answers.

In a similar vein as "[Marked as duplicate text doesn't make sense for questions that have no answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166537/marked-as-duplicate-text-doesnt-make-sense-for-questions-that-have-no-answer)", this banner is exceedingly unhelpful, and should probably be changed to something like "This question has already been asked here:".

Simple, true, effective.

Comment: `Exact Duplicate` and `This question has already been asked here` are... semantically the same, aren't they? One just has more words. Nitpicking, though; I do see your main point.

Comment: Maybe the other question can get a more helpful answer now that your question links to it. Linking the questions is the important part, even if the message text isn't always a perfect fit.

Comment: @Telthien It's all about the subtext.

Comment: @BoPersson Or people may ignore it because "it's already been answered".

Comment: @VxJasonxV I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Telthien OP isn't complaining about "exact duplicate", but about "this question already has an answer here". While a post might be an exact duplicate, that doesn't mean it has been answered, so he suggests to change the secondly quoted text.

Comment: ^ Exactly correct.