# Sum of votes on tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Doesn't it suppose to show in the left the total upvotes someone receives in the tag?

I see this in my profile:

[image]

Although if I manually sum the total votes I get 300+ (not 259).

How is this calculated?

Comment: Exact duplicate: [Tag scores have not updated; script did not run](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178114)

Comment: Only votes on answers are counted, and it's not dynamic (recalced once a day), and the score update currently seems to be slightly broken/erratic. Hover over the numbers to see the things it is counting.

Comment: How many times does someone have to report this before it gets the necessary attention?

Comment: @Maroun: did you remember not to count question scores?

Comment: @Mat Yes. I have over 259 for sure. (This is not the only problematic tag).

Comment: "*This question may already have an answer here:*" - **Wrong**. No answer there :(

Comment: @MarounMaroun the text is wrong but the concept is the same: answer to that question will also be answer to this question as they are both reporting the same problem.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well.. then this text is a bug :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun not really a bug, but it's already discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175162/152859). :)

Comment: This question may already have a comment :)

Comment: So this question is marked as duplicate. But when I'll get an answer please? :(