# Closing a duplicate question which is unanswered and/or closed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I was VTC a [duplicate question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36028/doctor-who-is-john-hurt-the-meta-crisis-tenth-doctor) where the [original question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36011/is-john-hurt-the-meta-crisis-tenth-doctor) was closed as not constructive. But I was surprised to see the description for the duplicate close reason :

> **duplicate**
>
> > This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

So, according to this, It would be OK to repost an unanswered question, even if it was closed question. The new question should then be closed the same way the original was.

Is the description for the duplicate close reason *incorrect*, or I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has [recently become impossible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate) to close a question as a duplicate of another one if the duplicate does not have an answer. That does not imply that reposting the question is okay if a non-answered dupe is around, but the description fits the practical situation.

If that dupe was already closed, the new one can simply be closed on similar grounds.

As stated by Mat however, this particular case is an exception since the OP of the duplicate is the OP of the originally closed question. In which case the vote to close as a duplicate does not have the same requirements. The description does not entirely match for that scenario, but it might not be really worth updating it. Such duplicates should simply be deleted.

Comment: There's an exception when it's an exact dup posted by the same user. Which is the in this question. The dup close vote couldn't have been registered if that wasn't the case, the Qs are brand new.

Comment: @Mat Ah, I see. I missed that point. Perhaps the description should be different for that particular scenario then.

Comment: Meh. Such dups should be deleted, they don't have any intrinsic value.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. You're right. Thanks for the heads-up.