# Closed question says duplicate has answer but doesn't

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions, wording

Refer to [this linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313761/how-to-check-user-and-password-in-delphi-that-users-create-by-net-sql-membershi). At the bottom, it says "This question has been asked before **and already has an answer**." If you look at the duplicate question, it does not have an answer. That is all.

Comment: Normally you can't even close as dupe unless the target has an answer. But there's an exception for questions from the same user. They just didn't extend that exception to the text description.

Comment: Perhaps questions with no answers should not be eligible to be marked as duplicates in the close interface.

Comment: @TravisJ They aren't, unless the OP of the duplicate is the OP of the original.

Comment: @Bart - I have had a question of mine on meta marked with a close vote and it linked to a question with no answers which was a duplicate of a question that had answers. The other two (one duplicate, one which was the legitimate) were not posted by me. Is that only a meta thing? I see that you are correct for stackoverflow ("This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"). I do not have the rep to test that on meta.

Comment: @TravisJ: The limit on dupes has been [introduced relatively recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933). When did you post that question and when did it receive that vote?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - This was perhaps ~10 days ago. I deleted the question though because the answer was a rather simple "No, that is not possible." which I received in comments and so I felt the question was not really constructive.

Comment: @TravisJ Do you happen to have a link? If I recall correctly, the Meta situation is slightly special.

Comment: @Bart - Sorry, I do not have a link. I am not sure how to locate my deleted questions.

Comment: Oh the irony! :)