# Duplicate questions with no answers

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I noticed that questions marked as duplicate have this placed at the top:

#### This question already has an answer here:

But what if question A gets marked as a duplicate of question B, but question B doesn't have any answers, does it still place this message at the top of question A?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. :-((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not after [recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate), no. Questions can only be marked as duplicates of questions that have answers. One exception: a question A can be marked as a duplicate of an answer-bereft question B if both A and B were asked by the same user.

Comment: What happens when the original answer is deprecated by an advance in technology.  Specifically, answers that were good for .net 3.5, but there's much better answers provided in later releases.

Comment: I don't think I follow you, @Garry. The same thing should happen as should happen were duplicates not in the picture - the answers should be updated.

Comment: That would be nice, but I didn't see much of that happening.  To go back to an old thread where the old 'answer' has been accepted and upvoted and canonized by Google and then put an answer at the bottom...  I'm not seeing where lots of people are doing that, but I'll keep my eyes peeled :)

Comment: I agree with you @Garry, that's not happening nearly as often as it should, but... that's not really related to dupes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do some more research and if my findings reach critical mass, I'll put them in meta