# Duplicate question target doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer, but the success notification still pops up when trying to associate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, notifications, duplicate-suggestions

After [Changes to "close as duplicate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate) it looks like you can't suggest a duplicate target, if that question doesn't have upvoted or accepted answer.

Well I had question that looked like a duplicate of another, so a user suggested that. But when I looked the upvoted answer was unhelpful so I downvoted it (there was an answer in the comments that I posted, but that's another story), and now there's not a viable answer on that duplicate target.

[image: Red error message saying "The original question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"]

Which is fine, except the submit button keeps spinning, and on refresh you get this success message:

[image: Great! We'll associate your post with these questions so future visitors can easily find the answer.]

That seems wrong and should be fixed, right?